# Proving associativity of symmetric set difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory, alternative-proof

I'm proving that $P(X)$ (the set of the subsets of $X$) is a ring with the following operations:
If $A, B \subset X$, then
$A+B := (A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B) $ and $A \cdot B = A \cap B $.

I have proven addition's associativity $ (A+B)+C=A+(B+C)$ by showing that

$$ ( (A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B) ) \cup C  \backslash ( (A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B)) \cap C  \\ = A \cup ((B \cup C ) \backslash (B \cap C)) \backslash A \cap ((B \cup C ) \backslash (B \cap C))  . $$

I wanted to know if there is an alternative way to prove this.

Comment: Addition is called the symmetric difference, denoted as $A \Delta B = (A\cup B) \setminus (A\cap B) = (A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)$
Verification of $(A\Delta B)\Delta C = A\Delta(B\Delta C)$ must be done in some elementary way if you want to prove it, so no - there is no "less exhaustive way". You could draw a Venn diagram, though.

Comment: Are Venn Diagrams rigorous enough?

Comment: @AlexR Thank you. At least I don't feel like my effort was in vain...

Comment: @Bob1123 No, not in this case.

Comment: Thank you all. Is this question too silly? Should I delete it or something?

Comment: Identify $A \subset X$ as a $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$-valued indicator function $\mathbf{1}_A : X \to \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ defined by $$ 1_{A}(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \in A \\ 0, & x \notin A \end{cases}. $$ Then you can easily prove that $\mathbf{1}_{A+B} = \mathbf{1}_A + \mathbf{1}_B$. This moves all the burden of set-operation to just algebraic operations, which makes proof almost trivial. For example, $$ \mathbf{1}_{A+(B+C)} = \mathbf{1}_A + \mathbf{1}_{B+C} = \mathbf{1}_A + \mathbf{1}_B + \mathbf{1}_C = \mathbf{1}_{A+B} + \mathbf{1}_C = \mathbf{1}_{(A+B)+C}. $$

Comment: @sos440 While a correct way, proving $1_{A+B} = 1_A + 1_B$ in the group of functions to $\mathbb F_2$ with addition is at least as much work as the direct approach.

Comment: @Wheepy It's up to you. You could ask for alternative proofs instead of easier proofs, wich would qualify sos440's comment as an answer and may be interesting.

Comment: @AlexR, I agree that proving the correspondence requires a bit of work, but still the outcome may be worth it if OP wants more than just manipulating a jumble of set operations.

Comment: @sos440 I agree with you on that part (In fact, the ring is isomorphic to $(\{f : X\to \mathbb F_2\}, +,\cdot)$ with the usual point-wise addition and multiplication operations)

Comment: @sos40 That looks like an interesting approach!

Comment: @AlexR Good idea, since what I wanted is impossible anyway and sos440's answer looks like a good alternative proof. I'll edit.

Comment: Of if you want to do it in a more elementary way, the following interpretation will be useful: $$ A + B = \{ x \in X : x \text{ lies in exactly one of } A \text{ or } B\}, $$ and more generally, you can establish the following interpretation $$ A + (B + C) = \{ x \in X : x \text{ lies in exactly odd number of } A, B \text{ and } C\} $$. By establishing exactly the same interpretation for $(A+B)+C$ you can prove that they are equal.

Comment: @sos440 that looks even better, considering my intention was doing things in a more elementary way. Thank you so much! If you want to post an answer, the question is already edited. =)